# Instructions for adding Contrib Module to OpenCV 3 using CMake GUI

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2017, cmake-gui, opencv-contrib

Im having problems building OpenCV with contrib module to enable SURF features using Visual Studio, CMake GUI, and OpenCV 3. I'm following the instructions on their website as best as I can, but they are not clear.

1. clone OpenCV Sources to `C:/OpenCV`
2. Clone the git repository https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib
3. Place the OpenCV_contrib-master folder into 
   **(??? unsure about this)**
   I chose `C:/opencv/sources/modules/opencv_contrib-master`
4. Run CMake GUI

Source code = `C:/OpenCV/sources`
Build directory = `C:/OpenCV/build`
Click Configure, Choose visual studio version
Scroll down, check OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE
OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH set to **(??? unsure about this)** set to `C:/opencv/sources/modules/opencv_contrib-master/modules`
Press Generate

5. Build in Visual Studio
   Open and build `C:/OpenCV/build/OpenCV.sln`

I got a lot of build errors in Visual Studio

Can anyone help with whats wrong?

Thank you,

Visual Studio pastebin
https://pastebin.com/KrDuMMke

CMake GUI pastebin
https://pastebin.com/N68r4xjf

Comment: "I chose `C:/opencv/sources/modules/opencv_contrib-master`" -- Why not just a top level directory, like for the main OpenCV source, e.g. `c:\opencv_contrib`, rather than hiding it in some random subdirectory deep inside the OpenCV sources? | After cloning, did you check out a stable branch of both, or are you trying to compile the in-development master branch?